# How to restore standard output's file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, printf, system-calls, file-descriptor

I need help to understand the file descriptors

So here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    close(1);
    //now opening a file so that it gets the lowest possible fd i.e. 1
    int fd=open("txt",O_RDWR);
    //check..
    printf("first printtf is executed\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    printf("ur value is %c\n",ch);

    printf("second printf is executed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

in the above program, I tried to redirect the output of `printf` to the `txt` file rather than the standard output, i.e. the terminal.
But how to restore the standard output file descriptor so that the `printf` again works as normal for the second case, i.e the second `printtf` should give output to the terminal only..

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do this would be to duplicate the output descriptor before closing it. You must look at [dup](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup).

Answer (score 0):

Before you close it I think you want to dup() it.
When you need it back, you can dup() the dup.

dup will always use the lowest descriptor

```
int out = dup(1);
close(1);
int fd = open();
...
close(fd);
dup(out);
close(out);
```

Warning: this is from memory and untested ;-)

Comment: When dup()-ing it "back" you have to use dup2 to duplicate the file descriptor __on__ the previously opened and closed '1'.

Comment: If you closed fd wouldn't dup still do it? (don't have a man page handy to check dup2)

Comment: Hmmm right, maybe dup() will dup it to 1... I think it needs a try !

Comment: yes sir, i just tried it and yes dup is also doing the work provided I close the least available and deisred fd..
rather dup2 is error prone(as i am guessing..) bcz. it is overriding the previously stored fd value....